# Method for finding $\tan(\theta)$ using $y$

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently studying GCSE Maths. I believe there is a way to find the $\tan$ of $\theta$ using the line  $x = 1$ and a circle radius of one on a graph. Is there a diagram I could use to explain this?

Comment: Where you wrote $\tan(x)$ in your title, did you mean $\tan\theta$, so that $x$ and $\theta$ are two different names you're using for the same thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I originally was going to ask another question.

Comment: The line is $x=1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#/media/File:Unitcircledefs.svg

Comment: With $x=1$ it would much more easier :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have now made the necessary edits.

Comment: What's "GCSE"? $\tan(\theta)$, where's the $\theta$? Are you referring to the slope of the line $x=1$?

Comment: @stud_iisc GCSE stands "General Certificate of Secondary Education", something that is referred as "Board Exams in India". See the comment by Yves on what he is referring. $\theta$ does not matter here.

Comment: @A---B Thanks for pointing out. But what does the OP require now?

Comment: "Is there a diagram I could use to explain this?" He needed a visual represtation of his claim.